# Podio API Pulling Wrong Data

Tags: php, api, podio

I have an app called Attendance. In that app item I have a number field called "# of Individuals" and a Relationship field for Campus. I am taking the total of all # of Individuals by Campus, but for some reason the total that is showing in my Podio report is not pulling correctly to the API.

For Example: Pelham Road (podio) = 69121 in php (API) = 60776

Here is the code that is giving the wrong number:

```
<?php
            error_reporting(0);
            require_once 'podio/PodioAPI.php';

            function codigo_fuente($url){
                $url = file($url);
                $codigo = '';
                foreach ($url as $numero => $linea) { 
                    $codigo .= '#<strong>' .$numero . '</strong> : ' . htmlspecialchars($linea) . '<br />';
                }
                return $codigo;
            }

            try {
                $weekday=30;
            foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
              //echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br />\r\n";
                    $weekday=$key;
                 }
              //  echo $weekday;


             Podio::setup("api key goes here", "api secret goes here");
            Podio::authenticate_with_password("usermail goes here", "user pass goes here");
            //Podio::authenticate_with_app("app id goes here", "app token goes here");
            $year = date("Y");
            $array1 = array();
            $array2 = array();
            $opt="";
            $name1="$month1 $FromDayLast/$ToDayLast, $yearLast";
            $name2="$month2 $FromDayActual/$ToDayActual, $yearActual";
            //echo "Name1 is".$name1;
            //echo "Name2 is ".$name2;
            $tabla="<table width=70%>
             <tr>
             <td style=width: 10%; font-size: 7pt;  valign=top><strong></strong></td>
               <td style=width: 10%; font-size: 7pt;  valign=top><strong></strong></td>
               <td style=width: 10%; font-size: 7pt;  valign=top><strong>$columna1</strong></td>
               <td style=width: 10%; font-size: 7pt;  valign=top><strong>$columna2</strong></td>
               <td style=width: 10%; font-size: 7pt;  valign=top><strong>$columna3</strong></td>
               <td style=width: 10%; font-size: 7pt;  valign=top><strong>$columna4</strong></td>
               <td style=width: 10%; font-size: 7pt;  valign=top><strong>$columna5</strong></td>

              </tr>
              ";



            $valores="";  $totalesLast1=""; $totalesLast2=""; $totalesLast3=""; $totalesActual="";
            $campaign = PodioItem::filter(8900539, array( 'sort_by' => 'title',
                                                            'sort_desc' => false)); // Get items from app with app_id=123
            $cant=0; $tot=0;
            foreach ($campaign as $item) {
                //echo "<br/>*************************************************<br/>";
             // echo "<br/>title::".$item->title;
              //echo "<br/>ID::".$item->item_id;

              $se=false;$se1=false;$se2=false;
                if($item->title=="Other"){
                  $se=true;
                }
                if($item->title=="Offsite"){
                    $se1=true;
                }
                if($item->title=="Central"){
                    $se2=true;
                }

                if($se==false && $se1==false && $se2==false){

              $cant = $cant +1;
                $tabla=$tabla."<tr>

               <td style=width: 20%; font-size: 7pt;  valign=top>"
              .$cant."</td>";



              $tabla=$tabla."<td style=width: 20%; font-size: 7pt;  valign=top>"
              .$item->title."</td>";

               $valores=$valores."|".$item->title;

                $app_reference_field_id = 116781926; 
               $attendancetype = 116781927;
               $date =  116781925;
               $adult = 9;
               $fourSeven = 10;
               $Fusion = 6;
               $Forge = 7;
               $WideOpen = 2;
               $Nursery = 5;
               $Preschool = 4;
               $Elementary = 8;

             //$date_lead_created=101404311;m
             $filter_target_item_id = $item->item_id;

            $attendance1 = PodioItem::filter(15171541, array( 'limit' => 400, 'offset' => 0, 
                  'filters' => array(
                    $app_reference_field_id => array($filter_target_item_id),
                    $date  => array(
                                      'from' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("01/01/$year")), 'to' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
                                    )
                  ),
                  'limit' => 200, 'offset' => $offset
                ));
                $valor = 0;

                if($attendance1->filtered>0){
                    $sum =0;
                    foreach($attendance1 as $item){

                        $sum = $sum + $item->fields["total-attendance"]->values;        
                                  //  echo "<br>Sum is ".$sum."<br>";
                    }

                    $weekNumber = date("W"); 
                            if($weekday==0)
                                $weekday=$weekNumber;
                    //$weekNumber = $weekNumber -1; 
                         //   echo "The Week Number is ".$weekNumber;
                    $valor = round(($sum/$weekday));
                       //  echo $sum."<br>";
                }else{
                    $valor = 0;
                }
                $totales = $totales.",".$valor;
                 $tot= $tot + $valor;
                $tabla=$tabla."<td style=width: 10%; font-size: 7pt;  valign=top>".$valor."</td>";
                }   
            }

            $tabla=$tabla."</table>";

            $totalesLast1 = substr($totalesLast1,0,strlen($totalesLast1)-1);
            $totalesLast2 = substr($totalesLast2,0,strlen($totalesLast2)-1);
            $totalesLast3 = substr($totalesLast3,0,strlen($totalesLast3)-1);
            //$totalesActual = substr($totalesActual,0,strlen($totalesActual)-1);

            //$totalesLast = $totalesLast ."|".$totalesActual;
            echo $tabla;

            //echo "<br/>totales::::$totalesLast";

            //print_r($array1);
            //print_r($array2);

            $mayor1 = $array1[12];
            $mayor2 = $array2[12];
            $mayor="";
            if($mayor1>$mayor2){
                $mayor=$mayor1;
            }else{
                $mayor=$mayor2;
            }

            $valores = substr($valores,1,strlen($valores)-1);
            $valores = str_replace(" ","%20",$valores);
            $name1 = str_replace(" ","%20",$name1);
            $name2 = str_replace(" ","%20",$name2);

            $columna1 = str_replace(" ","%20",$columna1);
            $columna2 = str_replace(" ","%20",$columna2);
            $columna3 = str_replace(" ","%20",$columna3);
            $columna4 = str_replace(" ","%20",$columna4);
            $columna5 = str_replace(" ","%20",$columna5);

            $valores = substr($valores,0,strlen($valores));
            $valores = str_replace(" ","%20",$valores);
            //echo $valores."<br/>";
            $totales = substr($totales,1,strlen($totales)-1);
            //echo $totales."<br/>";

            $totales2 = str_replace(",","|",$totales);

            $totaless="";
            $varr = explode(",",$totales);
            foreach($varr as $tt){
                //echo "<br/>valor::".$tt;
                $v1= $tt*100;
                $v2= $v1/$tot;
                $totaless = $totaless.",".$v2;
            }
            $totaless = substr($totaless,1,strlen($totaless)-1);

            $url = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=700x300&chd=t:$totaless&chl=$totales2&chdl=$valores&chco=FFFF10,FF0000,0072c6|ef3886|ff9900";
            //$url = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&chl=Hello|World";
            //echo $url;

            if(@copy($url, 'cinco.png')){
            //echo "image-saved";
            //echo "http://aparicio.website/uno.png";
            }else{
            //echo "failed"; 
            }

            }



            catch (PodioError $e) {
             echo "error $e"; // Something went wrong. Examine $e->body['error_description'] for a description of the error.
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: Hi John, the purpose of this "forum" is to give help and guidance on  programming problems. If you need general help, I suggest you submit a ticket on https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new.

If instead your problem is related to API or SDK usage, you should provide more information for us to help you (e.g. what are you doing, your code so far, the error you're encountering, etc...)

Comment: Hi @domokun I hav done that already and they pointed me here.

Comment: I am not sure what information you guys need to help me.

Comment: How is your report configured? Also, the code you show is missing some context. How did you populate $attendance1?

Comment: @ChrisPeters-Podio I have put all the code above

Comment: Please remove your API key and login information from the code sample. We would never need this information to help you out with your API calls. As a security measure we have revoked your API key and will lock your account until you reset your password. That being said give me a few minutes to read the code and figure out whats going on.

Comment: I see that it is already done. Thanks!

Comment: stackoverflow is great, but it's cumbersome to ask questions on individual lines of code. Could you do me a favor? Fork this repo, https://github.com/podio/podio-php and then push your code and open a pull request? I can comment inline of what is confusing and hopefully resolve your issue.

Comment: @ChrisPeters-Podio I am new to github, so could u explain how I would push my code up to it? I have already fork the repo and I know how to do a pull request, but do not know the best way to push up code for what you are asking.

Comment: @JohnBeasley If you do a git push to your repo and then visit the main podio-php repo github should give you an indicator that you can do a pull request. If not there is a button near the top labeled "New pull request"

Comment: @ChrisPeters-Podio just added the pull request

Comment: @JohnBeasley I just realized that what I asked you to do doesn't make any sense in regards to solving your problem. Looking at the code now.

Comment: @JohnBeasley It looks like your PodioItem::filter call is setting 'limit' and 'offset' twice with different values, and you're referencing an $offset variable that isn't set. This means that you're passing null as your offset. Not sure if this is the problem, but it's probably not what you intended. Also you are rounding the value `$valor = round(($sum / $weekday))` `$weekday` might not be what you expect.  `foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        //echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br />\r\n";
        $weekday = $key;
    }`

Comment: This worked thank you @ChrisPeters-Podio

Comment: @JohnBeasley Excellent. Can you mark the provided answer as correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your `PodioItem::filter` call is setting 'limit' and 'offset' twice with different values, and you're referencing an `$offset` variable that isn't set. This means that you're passing null as your offset. Not sure if this is the problem, but it's probably not what you intended.

Also, you are rounding the value `$valor = round(($sum / $weekday))` so `$weekday` might not be what you expect, and the way you're getting `$weekday` from the `$_GET` as the `$key` is probably not what you intended either.